# purpose of .RDataTmp temporary file? [R]

Tags: r

what is the purpose of the R temporary file that is created in every directory where a workspace is saved? What data does it contain and is it safe to delete?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That file is a holding file for `save.image()` while R waits for its `file` argument to succeed. From `help(save.image)` and its `safe` argument -

> **safe** - logical. If TRUE, a temporary file is used for creating the saved workspace. The temporary file is renamed to file if the save succeeds. This preserves an existing workspace file if the save fails, but at the cost of using extra disk space during the save.

So the file contains the entire workspace image and it is probably best to just leave it there in case R fails to save the workspace normally.

I'm also guessing that if you see this file, R has already failed to rename the file so you may want to search for `file` and check its contents before deleting the temporary file.

Comment: the only thing that doesn't make sense is that the file size is so much bigger than my saved workspace file size.

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience with this file, but it may be that the temp file is not compressed and the saved file is.  Have you tried to load them both in separate new R sessions for comparison?

Comment: based on this description I think it is safe to delete IF you have a workspace file saved already, as it probably contains redundant or old information.